# how to apply coupon in stripe for particular product (plan)? POST details: $request->plan price id , $coupon => coupon id $card['id'] => card token

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, payment, cartalyst

I am added a coupon for abc product, while create subscription i can apply that coupon for all
products. I want it can apply to only abc product. i m using
https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0#subscriptions documentation.

```
 $stripe->subscriptions()->create($stripe_customer_id, [
             'plan'   => $request->plan,
             'coupon' => $coupon,
             'default_payment_method' => $card['id'],
         ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a coupon to a subscription that will be restricted to a particular product by using the `applies_to` attribute. For example, in the following code, the coupon will only apply to `prod_xxx`, so when a subscription is created with a price from prod_xxx but also a price from prod_yyy, the discount will only apply to the amount of prod_xxx/price_xxx

```
$coupon = $stripe->coupons->create([
  'percent_off' => 25,
  'duration' => 'repeating',
  'duration_in_months' => 3,
  'applies_to' => ["products" => ["prod_xxx"]]
]);

$stripe->subscriptions->create([
  'coupon' => $coupon->id,
  'customer' => 'cus_xxx',
  'items' => [
    ['price' => 'price_xxx'], # <-- coupon will apply
    ['price' => 'price_yyy'],
  ],
]);
```

Comment: Yes, i did the same,Please check response https://i.imgur.com/7IkWLs7.png.
When we add product in applies_to, we can see that product is applicable to only that coupon, it is correct. 
But when we redeem the coupon using subscription create API, i m sending price id in plan key.It will applicable to all price id or product.

Comment: The Plans API is a deprecated API in favour of Prices, which are backwards compatible wit Plans. The recommendation is to use Prices and pass them as part of items array: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-items-price. Your account is already creating Products (prod_xxx) and Prices (price_xxx) so if you use those the above should work.